# ¿How can I stop my number sequence from growing?

Tags: javascript, function, numbers, sequence

I am trying to make a sequence of numbers that starts with number 10 and grows like 10...11...12...13 etc every two seconds. But lets say that I want it to stop when it reaches 100, how do i do it. So far I have this.Any ideas?

```
function conteo(num){
setInterval(function(){document.write(num++ + "..."); }, 2000);
```

}conteo(10)

Comment: How about some `if`?

Comment: save the result of `setInterval()` to a variable: `intervalId = setInterval(...)` and you can use that to cancel an interval like `clearInterval(intervalId)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can clear the interval:

```
function conteo(num){
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if(num == 100) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
        document.write(num++ + "..."); 
    }, 2000);
}
conteo(10)
```

This will check if `num` is equal to 100, then clear interval if true, but keep going.

Comment: thank you, I just started to learn JavaScript last week , I still have a lot to practice.

Answer (score 0):

Save the `setInterval` reference call into a variable:

```
var conteoInterval;

function conteo(num){
  conteoInterval = setInterval(function(){document.write(num++ + "..."); },  2000);
}
```

And to stop the interval, just clear its reference, doing this:

```
clearInterval(conteoInterval);
```

Comment: Thank you, i wasnt relly sure how to use clearInterval, i will pracice more.